# Derivative definition + question

Tags: functions, derivatives

Given the fact that $f$ is differentiable at point $a$ and $f'(a)=5$ calculate the following expression:
$\displaystyle \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a+3h)}{h} = \,\,\,?$

Is it possible to define the definition of derivative as $\,\,\,\displaystyle \lim_{\Delta\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x)-f(x-\Delta)}{\Delta}\,\,\,$ instead of $\,\,\,\displaystyle \lim_{\Delta\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+\Delta)-f(x)}{\Delta}\,\,\,$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a+3h)}{h}&=\dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}+\dfrac{f(a)-f(a+3h)}{h}\\
&=\dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}-\dfrac{f(a+3h)-f(a)}{h}\\
&=\dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}-3\cdot\dfrac{f(a+3h)-f(a)}{3h}\\
&\rightarrow f'(a)-3f'(a).
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{f(x)-f(x-\Delta)}{\Delta}=-\dfrac{f(x-\Delta)-f(x)}{\Delta}=\dfrac{f(x-\Delta)-f(x)}{-\Delta}\rightarrow f'(x).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Using Taylor series
$$f(a+n h)=f(a)+h n f'(a)+\frac{1}{2} h^2 n^2 f''(a)+O\left(h^3\right)$$
$$f(a+h)-f(a+3h)=-2 h f'(a)-4 h^2 f''(a)+O\left(h^3\right)$$
$$\frac{f(a+h)-f(a+3h) } h=-2 f'(a)-4 h f''(a)+O\left(h^2\right)$$